# Node Js Issue: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: node.js, npm, proxy

I am writing a node application to make a https request to an external URL. I am behind a corporate proxy and I have set

```
>npm config set proxy http://proxy.sample.example.org:8080
>npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.sample.example.org:8080
```

I am able to download the node dependencies without issues. But, When I try to hit the external URL, it throws up the following error.

```
    { Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND example.net example.net:443
    at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
    code: 'ENOTFOUND',
    errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
    syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
    hostname: 'example.net',
    host: 'example.net',
    port: 443 }
```

The same applies to even google.com. Code is as below.

```
var request = require('request');
request.get(   
    {
    url : connUrl,//This is set to be https://example.net
    },function (error, response, body) {
       //Print response code
        console.log(body);
        console.log(error);
      });
```

Can someone  please suggest where I am going wrong

Comment: Because your proxy is not set for the node application.  Set up the proxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For [Requests](https://github.com/request/request) module, you can set the proxy using the `proxy` options.
Try something like this,

```
request.get({
      proxy: "proxy",
      url : connUrl,//This is set to be https://example.net
    },function (error, response, body) {
       //Print response code
        console.log(body);
        console.log(error);
});
```

Alternatively you could also set the `http_proxy` and/or `https_proxy` environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Set npm proxy with username and password. *Safe to have password as Alphanumeric in this scenario* ***(proxy is setup with username and password in most corporate environments)***

```
npm config set proxy http://username:password@10.81.82.100:80
npm config set https-proxy https://username:password@10.81.82.100:80
```

Set npm proxy without username and password

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
```

Adding to answer of @Malice, setting temporary proxy using environment variables

```
set http_proxy=http://username:password@10.81.82.100:80
set https_proxy=https://username:password@10.81.82.100:80
```