# Node JS: Call Multiple API Calls in parallel using request

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying call multiple API in request but getting below exception when I am running the application.

Node Version: 10.15.2
NPM Version: 6.4.1

I already set proxy at global level using npm config set http-proxy in the terminal

Exception:

```
C:\Data\NPM\Testing>node server.js
node.js application starting...
Node HTTP server is listening
One
two
{ Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mocktarget.apigee.net mocktarget.apigee.net:80
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:57:26)
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'mocktarget.apigee.net',
  host: 'mocktarget.apigee.net',
  port: 80 }
{ Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND httpbin.org httpbin.org:443
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:57:26)
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'httpbin.org',
  host: 'httpbin.org',
  port: 443 }
```

Code:

```
var http = require('http');
var async = require('async');
var request = require('request');

console.log('node.js application starting...');

var svr = http.createServer(function (req, resp) {
  async.parallel({
    one: function (callback) {
      console.log("One");
      request('http://mocktarget.apigee.net/json', function (error, response, body) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    },
    two: function (callback) {
      console.log("two");
      request('https://httpbin.org/headers', function (error, response, body) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
  }, function (err, results) {
    console.log(results);
  });
});

svr.listen(9000, function () {
  console.log('Node HTTP server is listening');
});
```

Please help me how to resolve this issue if anyone knows. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690803/node-js-getaddrinfo-enotfound)

Comment: Have a look at this: Node Js Issue: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND[](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48275758/node-js-issue-getaddrinfo-enotfound)
This seems like a DNS issue